# How to prevent http session to expire while WebSocket is open

Tags: java, spring-security, websocket

I have a web application which is secured through `Spring Security`.

The application creates a `WebSocket` and pushes notification messages to the clients.

However, since sometimes there are no page reloads for a long time, but only `WebSocket` messages, the `HTTP session` expires and the `WebSocket` gets closed.

Is there a way to make `Spring Security` keep the session alive as long as a `WebSocket` is connected, even no HTTP requests come in?

Here is my `Spring Security` configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .csrf().disable()
    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest()
    .access("hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1/32') or hasIpAddress('192.168.0.0/24') or hasIpAddress('192.168.1.0/24')")
    .and()
    .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
    .loginProcessingUrl("/checklogin")
    .usernameParameter("user")
    .passwordParameter("pass")
    .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
    .failureUrl("/login?failed=true")
    .permitAll()
    .and()
    .logout()
    .logoutUrl("/logout")
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
    .permitAll();
}
```

When I am not in any of the allowed networks, I get the login-form. Once logged in with `ROLE_ADMIN` I stop getting `WebSocket` messages afer a while. When I then refresh the page, I am redirected to the login mask, so most probably the session is expired... :-)

Comment: Are yo sure this is happening? It doesn't seem very likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [spring-session](http://projects.spring.io/spring-session/)

> WebSocket - provides the ability to keep the HttpSession alive when receiving WebSocket messages